# I am using the POS API:Web callBack to get the Trans.ID, it works. How do I get the amount of the transaction?

Tags: api, square, pos

We are opening the Square app on an IOS device via a URL.The app opens with the amount to be charged.

We get the response via the POS API callBack which includes the transactionID and client transaction ID.

This all works fine. My question is what is the best way to get the amount of the transaction? We need to confirm that the balance due is zero before printing the receipt. The user could change the amount before processing the card. We need to know the actual amount charged.

Thanks, Mike

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by confirming the balance due is zero. Once you have a transactionId, that means the payment is complete, and the card has already been charged. Could you clarify?

Comment: To answer your main question, though: use `RetrieveTransaction` with the `transactionId` to look up the details. It's deprecated, but still works until we move off of providing `transactionId` in POS API. https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2#endpoint-transactions-retrievetransaction